# Code snippets/blocks within YFM variables

Tags: yaml, assemble, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to take a code snippet from Litmus to use within my Assemble.io project (HTML emails). A typical code block looks like this:

```
<style>@media print{ #_t { background-image: url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?p&d=%%Email%%');}} div.OutlookMessageHeader {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')} table.moz-email-headers-table {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')} blockquote #_t {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')} #MailContainerBody #_t {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')}</style><div id="_t"></div>
<img src="https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?d=%%Email%%" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Ideally, I would love to just stick this whole thing into a YFM variable, which I've tried unsuccessfully. I believe the parser is getting stuck on the #, the quotes, the curly braces, or any combination of the above. I've tried wrapping the code block in '', "", ``, and ```, none of which work. Right now I've taken the variable part of that block (in this case, 0me4e2bg) and used just that in my YFM, which works well enough but I'm sure using CSS and HTML blocks/snippets in YFM has happened to someone else and I'm curious if there is a solution? Is it just that I'm not escaping it properly? Thanks!

EDIT: After trying the answer suggested by Anthon, I get the following error

```
can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed
```

which looks like it's triggered by the @ in @media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scalar in YAML doesn't need quotes unless it has special characters, and in your case it does. Quoted scalars can use single quotes in which existing single quotes would need to be repeated, or double quotes in which you can use backslash escapes.

If you want your string as is using literal block quoting is most of the best approach, the only thing that has problems with is starting whitespace and end-of-line blanks (i.e. before the newline). You should be able to assign your code block to the variable `code` as follows:

```
---
title: YAML Front Matter
description: A very simple way to add structured data to a page.
code: |
  <style>@media print{ #_t { background-image: url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?p&d=%%Email%%');}} div.OutlookMessageHeader {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')} table.moz-email-headers-table {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')} blockquote #_t {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')} #MailContainerBody #_t {background-image:url('https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?f&d=%%Email%%')}</style><div id="_t"></div>
  <img src="https://0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg?d=%%Email%%" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
---
<h1> {{ title }} </h1>
```

You have to make sure the indentation under `code` is consistent, which is normally easier than parsing the string for characters to escape.

You can e.g. [check online](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---%0Atitle%3A%20YAML%20Front%20Matter%0Adescription%3A%20A%20very%20simple%20way%20to%20add%20structured%20data%20to%20a%20page.%0Acode%3A%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%40media%20print%7B%20%23_t%20%7B%20background-image%3A%20url%28%27https%3A//0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg%3Fp%26d%3D%25%25Email%25%25%27%29%3B%7D%7D%20div.OutlookMessageHeader%20%7Bbackground-image%3Aurl%28%27https%3A//0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg%3Ff%26d%3D%25%25Email%25%25%27%29%7D%20table.moz-email-headers-table%20%7Bbackground-image%3Aurl%28%27https%3A//0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg%3Ff%26d%3D%25%25Email%25%25%27%29%7D%20blockquote%20%23_t%20%7Bbackground-image%3Aurl%28%27https%3A//0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg%3Ff%26d%3D%25%25Email%25%25%27%29%7D%20%23MailContainerBody%20%23_t%20%7Bbackground-image%3Aurl%28%27https%3A//0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg%3Ff%26d%3D%25%25Email%25%25%27%29%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22_t%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A//0me4e2bg.emltrk.com/0me4e2bg%3Fd%3D%25%25Email%25%25%22%20width%3D%221%22%20height%3D%221%22%20border%3D%220%22%20/%3E%0A---%0A%3Ch1%3E%20%7B%7B%20title%20%7D%7D%20%3C/h1%3E&type=json) that the first part is valid YAML.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that returns errors when I run it like that (i'll edit my original question with the errors)

Comment: @pipboy3000 I updated my answer with a link to a YAML 1.1 parser that (correctly) parses this. It also works on my YAML 1.2 compatible parser. It looks like you found a bug in js-yaml or the way assemble.io uses it and should report it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I submitted a bug to the assemble project team on github. https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/756

Comment: this wouldn't have anything to do with assemble. assemble uses gray-matter to parse front-matter. and since gray-matter just passes a string to a parser - in this case js-yaml, gray-matter wouldn't be able to do anything about the error either. this sounds like a js-yaml issue